# Create a table from other table depending on a value NUMBERS

Tags: numbers, iwork

I have a table with a list of items, and I want to create a new table with all the values that contains a certain value.

In the first list, are all the profucts that I usually buy and a cell with "YES or NO"

In the second list I want to put only the items with a "YES" on the first table.

See image below.

Thanks for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to remove empty rows from the second table, but I can make only the ones with YES show up.

---

### Making it happen

First, select the first cell of your second table ("carrot", the headers don't matter), and type this in it:

`=if(`

You'll see it transform into a function. Then click the YES/NO column of the same row to add it to the table. Click on the dropdown in the new addition to the formula box, and check "Preserve Column".

[image: Fig. 1]

This will allow you to copy and paste over the entire row without worrying about the referenced column changing. Add `= "YES"` to the end. You should now have something like this:

`IF(<Table 1::$B2> = "YES"`

Next, add a comma, and click the corresponding cell in your first table:

`IF(<Table 1::$B2> = "YES",<Table 1::A2>`

Do **not** preserve the column on this one. You want it to show the corresponding cell in the table. Add `,"")`, like so:

`IF(<Table 1::$B2> = "YES",<Table 1::A2>,"")`

Hit the big green checkmark, and copy and paste the cell to fill the second table (or just as many items as you want to show), and you're done!

---

### So what does all this gobbledygook mean?

The IF command has three parts:

IF(*condition*, *if-true*, *if-false*)

If the *condition* is true, it shows the *if-true* portion, otherwise it shows the *if-false* portion. So it shows the value of the other cell if the deciding cell is "YES", or blank ("") if not.